# R: Creating new data frame from text list using gsub, and grep

Tags: r, dataframe, text, gsub

How can I extract important info - name, age, (illness), and weight- from text list and create a new  data list or frame?

```
test<-c("James is approximately age 25 & 26 weighted 130lbs", 
        "Angelina is age 40 (Diabetes)", 
        "Harry Peterson is male with ages 27")
```

To do that

I  was able to subset names/ and illness inside parenthesis.

```
> sapply(strsplit(test, "\\s+"),"[",1)
[1] "James"    "Angelina" "Harry"

> gsub("[\\(\\)]","\\1", regmatches(test, gregexpr("(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))",test, perl=T)))
[1] "character0" "Diabetes"   "character0"
```

**HOWEVER,** fail to subset age 25  &  26, and grep 'ages'

```
> paste(grep(pattern="age",  trimws(strsplit(test, " ")[[1]]), value = TRUE),as.numeric(sub(".*age. 
(\\d+).*", "\\1", test[[1]])) )
[1] "age 25"
```

**How can I extract all the number and ampersand together from text ?** like "age 25 & 26"

**How can I set pattern for age that extracts age and ages?**  ages 27 -> "age 27", weighted -> "weight 130"

**How can I  grep all info as this order below, instead of subset names, ages, weight and () separately?**

```
 c("James","age 25 & 26", "weight 130", "Angelina","age 40", "Diabetes", "Harry", "age 27")
```

**and eventually create a data frame as below**

```
          age        weight  illness   
James     "25 & 26"  "130"   NA        
Angelina  "40"       NA     "Diabetes"
Harry     "27"       NA      NA
```

If you can only answer partially which will be helpful as well.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you only extracting the first name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
gsub(" .*", "", test)
# [1] "James"    "Angelina" "Harry"   

trimws(gsub("ages?", "", regmatches(test, gregexpr("ages?\\s*[-&0-9 ]+\\b", test, perl = TRUE))))
# [1] "25 & 26" "40"      "27"     

weights <- regmatches(test, gregexpr("weight(s|ed)? [0-9]+(lb|pound|kg|g)?", test))
weights[lengths(weights) < 1] <- NA_character_
trimws(gsub("weight(s|ed)?", "", unlist(weights)))
# [1] "130lb" NA      NA     

ill <- regmatches(test, gregexpr("(?<=\\().*(?=\\))", test, perl = TRUE))
ill[lengths(ill) < 1] <- NA_character_
unlist(ill)
# [1] NA         "Diabetes" NA
```

Comment: thank you so much, but 25&26 is still not grepped?                                        > trimws(gsub("ages?", "", regmatches(test, gregexpr("ages?\\s*[-&0-9]+\\b", test, perl = TRUE))))
[1] "25" "40" "27"

Comment: copy/paste error, my bad ... there's a space in the pattern.

Comment: the updated code works great!!!  Last question that if I want to drop lb(kg) for weight,  numeric only, then what would be adjusted code? Appreciate it

Comment: Just remove that portion from the pattern, resulting in `"weight(s|ed)? [0-9]+"`. I added it as a bonus in case it could be useful (since assuming all units are the same has been the cause of many problems in past projects of mine). Over to you.